# Apple Silicon issue - Rust binary shipped as Xcframework working in simulator on Release but not Debug

Tags: ios, xcode, rust, ios-simulator, xcframework

Hi I'm trying to build a Xcframework for IOS with rust ffi.

I've successfully built the framework and have it imported into the project working. However it only works on the Simulator with the Xcode build config set to `Release` mode. When I switch to `Debug`, I get the issue:

```
Could not find module 'AttestationBindings' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: /Users/donal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-ios-sdk-app-cgpqpyzzdlmlryeyqskhrbzgljum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/test-ios-sdk-app/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AttestationBindings.swiftmodule
```

**Steps to build:**

I have built the rust framework for the simulator targets using:

```
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target aarch64-apple-ios-sim --release
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target x86_64-apple-ios --release
```

and then combined these two binaries into a fat library using lipo -create:

```
lipo -create \
  -output "$XCFRAMEWORK_ROOT/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/$FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework/$FRAMEWORK_NAME" \
  "$TARGET_DIR/aarch64-apple-ios-sim/$BUILD_PROFILE/$LIB_NAME" \
  "$TARGET_DIR/x86_64-apple-ios/$BUILD_PROFILE/$LIB_NAME"
```

I added the header files so the directory looks like so:

```
../target/AttestationBindings.xcframework
├── Info.plist
├── ios-arm64
│   └── AttestationBindings.framework
│       ├── AttestationBindings
│       ├── Headers
│       │   ├── AttestationBindings.h
│       │   └── AttestationBindingsRustFFI.h
│       ├── Info.plist
│       └── Modules
│           └── module.modulemap
└── ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
    └── AttestationBindings.framework
        ├── AttestationBindings
        ├── Headers
        │   ├── AttestationBindings.h
        │   └── AttestationBindingsRustFFI.h
        ├── Info.plist
        └── Modules
            └── module.modulemap
```

I then zip the xcframework directory and publish it. It works fine on actual devices and in  Release simulator but not when the build config is set to `Debug`. Any idea why?

I've seen a lot of problems developers were having with M1 and simulators but not with only Debug builds